# Windows 8 DNS client

Tags: windows-8, dns, 64-bit

I've got DNS problems with certain domain names, e.g. "answers.microsoft.com". The behavior is consistent across browsers: all of them complain "unable to resolve the host name". If I open a command line and type "ping -4 answers.microsoft.com", ping resolves the IP address, and the web site starts working in all browsers.

Windows 7 x64 worked great on the same hardware with the same router settings.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: stop the DNS client and look if it works now.

Comment: Yes, stopping the DNS client helped. Should I disable the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok if it works without the DNS client, stop the service completely (set the starttype to disabled with services.msc). Now the DNS requests are no longer cached, but it works.

Comment: OK thanks.. I wonder when will Microsoft fix the Windows 8 :-(